# Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler AllTasks not working properly

Tags: c#

this is the task sheduler list on my pc as seen in Task Sheduler:

[image]

running this code:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TaskService x = new TaskService();
            foreach (Task z in x.AllTasks)
            {
                if (z.Name.ToLower().Contains("intel"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(z.Name + " " + z.Enabled + " " + z.IsActive);
                } 
            }
        }
```

shows zero output which means that x.AllTasks is not working properly or is it?
the task defined in the intel folder is called: "intel telemetry".

also why is the code he offers on github in the Microsoft.Win32 namespace...isn't that Microsoft's playground?

Comment: Intel may not be part of the name.  Remove the IF and get a list of all names and then refine you code.  Intel may be part of the type and not the task name.

Comment: Try to debug it and inspect the content of "x.AllTasks" or disable the "if" and see what it prints out.